# Does a loan for purchasing land provide a tax benefit?

Tags: india, loans, home-loan, personal-loan

I want to take a loan for land. In the future we want to build house on it, but now we can only afford the land. Would this be a personal loan or home loan?

If I take this land loan can I benefit in income-tax return?

And in the future I also want to build a house on it so by that time the loan will be running. Can I get a second loan?

Comment: Just an addition, I am a salaried person.  And I am 33 year old.

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to ask the bank